# Facility location on a tree

Tags: dynamic-programming, trees, recursion, vertex-cover

> **Question:**
>
> Given a tree representing a neighbourhood where each node is a house.
>   Assign an antenna to each node such that the whole tree is covered.
>
> An antenna of strength **0** can only provide a signal to **itself**.
>   An antenna of strength **j** can provide a signal to itself and nodes
>   that are **j steps away** from it. The cost of building an antenna at
>   a house is given by a cost function **f(n<sub>i</sub>, j)** where
>   n<sub>i</sub> is the **i**'th node and **j** is the signal strength. Additionally the cost of an antenna with strength j has to be less or equal the cost of an antenna with strength i if j is weaker than i.

```
     7 
     | 
     6 
   / | \
  3  4  5
 / \
1   2
```

For example an optimal solution in this tree for a cost function **f(n<sub>i</sub>, j) = j + 1** would be to place an antenna of strength 2 at node 6.

This is a school assignment and the ultimate goal is to write a dynamic programm that can solve it in O(n^2). As far as my understanding goes the 'trick' of dynamic programming is to find a recursive algorithm that can solve the problem in exp. time and then use a table to cache the intermediate answers that build upon each other to improve the time complexity.

I fail in seeing a recurrence in the problem and and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Cute and by no means easy problem! The "trick" of DP is figuring out which *side conditions* you can add to subproblems to make it possible to solve them all in terms ot solutions to smaller subproblems. Hint: Root the tree somewhere, and try solving subproblems of the form "The cheapest (partial) solution for the subtree rooted at $v$ and having *excess* $m$", where $v$ is any vertex and $m$ is an integer in the range $[-|V|, |V|]$. Getting the time down from $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^2)$ is tricky in itself, and involves computing only certain "baseline" sums and using subtraction to get the others.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Could you maybe elaborate on the excess part ? What exactly is the excess of a tree ?

Comment: This is supposed to be a learning exercise, and that would give the game away I think. "Excess" is just a term I came up with -- it doesn't have any standard meaning. FWIW I've solved many DP problems and it took me a couple of hours to come up with a working strategy for this one; if you are new to DP, I suggest starting with much easier problems. Independent Set on a tree is a nice one.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to help me. I had started looking at some examples of DP problems and fell like i'm getting a grip for it. Will definitely hav a look at that one.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok now I have been looking at two problems mainly. The first one was Independent Set on trees and I have noticed big similarities to my problem and I think to DP Problems on trees in general. First of all I have found that I can consider the OPT solution for the smallest subproblem, that is a leaf, is to build an antenna of strength 0. The idea is now to build upon that by calculating the OPT(v) where v is the parent node of leafs using the OPT value of its children which is 0. But I am worried now that the OPT value of its children doesn't simply imply the OPT of its parent.

Comment: What brings me to Subset Sum. To solve this problem they introduce a second parameter in Kleinberg and Tardos to calculate OPT of a subproblem like OPT(n,w). My idea is now to do the same for every node what would be calculating a N x N table for every Node which should bring me to the desired O(n^3) runtime. I would do OPT(v,e) where e would be the excess you stated obove. Does this sound about right ?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Please credit the source of all copied material (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @D.W. As I stated in my question this problem is a school assignment and afaik the source is not publicly available.

Comment: You can still credit the author of the problem (e.g., your professor/instructor) and the course where you encountered it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I have tried computing the OPT cost for every problem considering the excess where excess is the number of nodes that are covered multiple  times (excessively) and the ones that are not covered would be negative excess but I can‘t figure out how to get the OPT of the next bigger subproblem. Can you maybe give me another hint or tell me if i‘m on the right path

Comment: Although this question was raised earlier, I am voting to close it as a duplicate of a later question, [Minimum cost of "signal" cover in a tree with DP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127227/minimum-cost-of-signal-cover-in-a-tree-with-dp) since the later question has been more fortunate to receive an answer.

Comment: The probable source for this problem is a homework assignment from the "Algorithmentheorie" course at Technische Universität Berlin. The authors credited on the assignment are: Niedermeier, Nichterlein, Bentert and Heeger.