# Minimum cost of "signal" cover in a tree with DP

Tags: dynamic-programming, trees

I'm given a (not necessarily binary) tree. Now every node can have a signal with range $i$, reaching all nodes being at most $i$ edges away. The cost of a signal is determined by a function $f(n, i)$ with $n$ being a node and $i$ being the signal strenght. The cost for each node may vary, the only assumption one can make is that $f(n, i) \geq f(n, j)$ for $i > j$.

I need to find the minimum cost to cover the whole tree.

Example:

[image: tree]

For $f(n, i) = (i + 1)^2$, the minimum cost would be 7:

Setting a signal with strenght 0 for every node covers the whole tree for the cost of 7. Setting a signal with strenght 1 for the nodes $b$ and $c$ covers the tree for the cost of 8 and setting a signal with strenght 2 for node $a$ results in a cost of 9.

Using Dynamic Programmming this task should be achieved in $O(n^2)$. This is an assignment so I'd be grateful for tips.

Comment: Is it the tree rooted/directed? (The signal only reach children but no parents) As nothing is stated regarding this I'm assuming it isn't, but the arrows in the picture suggest this.

Comment: Already answered my question with this line: `Setting a signal with strenght 1 for the nodes b and c covers the tree for the cost of 8 `

Comment: Hint: for $i \ge 0$ and a vertex $v$, define $OPT_{down}[v,i]$ as the minimum cost needed to cover the subtree rooted at $v$ if all the nodes at distance $<i$ from $v$ are always considered as covered. Define  $OPT_{up}[v,i]$ as the minimum cost needed to cover the subtree $T_v$ rooted at $v$ with the constraint that the selected signal strenghts should also be a fesible solution for the tree obtained by appending  $T_v$ at the end of a path of $i$ vertices.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: @Steven Could you elaborate on $OPT_{up}$? I don't understand what you mean by "appending $T_v$ at the end of a path of i vertices". Thank you for your tip

Comment: Imagine a rooted tree whose first $i$ levels form a path. I.e., on level $j=1,\dots,i$ there is only a single vertex $u_j$. Now append $T_v$ to the path by adding an edge from $u_i$ to the root $v$ of $T_v$. (in the special case $i=0$ the resulting tree is $T_v$ itself). 
This was a bit annoying to state formally but the intuition behind $OPT_{up}[v,i]$  is easy: $OPT_{up}[v,i]$ is the minimum cost needed to cover $T_v$ if the "leftover signal" that "goes out of $T_v$" is strong enough to reach vertices at distance $i$ from $v$.

Comment: @Steven Would you mind giving me the recursive formular? Maybe that'll help me to code

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be your tree, and root it in an arbitrary vertex $r$.
Given a vertex $v$, let $T_v$ denote the subtree of $T$ rooted at $v$.
For simplicity, let $f(0, v) = 0$.

For $i \ge 0$, define $D[v,i]$ as the minimum cost needed to cover the subtree rooted at $v$ if all the nodes at distance smaller than $i$ from $v$ are always considered as covered.  Intuitively this means that the signal "coming into $T_v$" is strong enough to cover all vertices of $ T_v$ at distance at most $i-1$ from $v$.

For $i \ge 0$, define $U[v,i]$ as the minimum cost needed to cover the subtree $T_v$ rooted at $v$ with the constraint that the selected signal strengths should also be a feasible solution for the tree obtained by appending a path of $i$ vertices to $v$. Intuitively this means that the signal "outgoing from $T_v$" is strong enough to cover all vertices of $T \setminus T_v$ at distance at most $i$ from $v$.

Notice that, by definition, $D[v,i] = U[v,i]$.

If $v$ is a leaf of $T$, then
$$
D[v, i] =
\begin{cases}
f(v, 0) & \mbox{if } i=0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } i>0 \\
\end{cases},
$$
and
$$
U[v, i] = f(v, i).
$$

If $v$ is not a leaf of $T$, then let $C_v$ be the set of children of $v$.
For $i=0, \dots, n-1$:

$$
U[v, i] = \min
\begin{cases} 
U[v, i+1] & \mbox{only if $i \neq n-1$}\\
f(v,i) +  \sum_{u \in C_v} D[u, i]    \\
\min_{z \in C_v} \left\{ U[z, i+1] +  \sum_{u \in C_v \setminus {z}} D[u, i] \right\}  & \mbox{only if $i \neq n-1$}
\end{cases},
$$

and, for $i=1,\dots,n$:

$$
D[v, i] =
\min
\begin{cases} 
D[v, i-1] \\
\sum_{u \in C_v} D[u, i-1]
\end{cases} 
$$

You can then compute all values $U[v, i]$ and $D[v,i]$ where $v$s are considered in postoder w.r.t. $T$ and the order of subproblems for a fixed vertex $v$ is $U[v,n-1], \dots, U[v,1], U[v,0] = D[v,0], D[v,1], \dots, D[v,n]$.

As far as the computational complexity is concerned notice that there are $O(n^2)$ subproblems.
The *overall* time needed to evaluate the second argument of the minimum of $U[v,i]$ and $D[v,i]$ is $O(n^2)$ since, for each value of $i$, computing $\sum_{u \in C_v} D[u, i]$ takes time proportional to $|C_v|$ and $\sum_v |C_v| = O(n)$.

Suppose then that all the values $\sum_{u \in C_v} D[u, i]$ are known for free (since the time needed to compute them has already been accounted for).
The *overall* time needed to evaluate the third argument of the minimum of $U[v,i]$ is again $O(n^2)$ since, for each value of $i$, $\sum_{u \in C_v \setminus {z}} D[u, i]$ can be found in time $O(1)$ by difference, and the inner minimum ranges over $|C_v|$ elements. Once again  $\sum_v |C_v| = O(n)$.

Comment: $\min_{z \in C_v} \left\{ U[z, i+1] +  \sum_{u \in C_v \setminus {z}} D[u, i] \right\}$ also can't work if $i = n - 1$ just like $U[v, i+1]$, right?

Comment: With $U$ and $D$ calculated, how do I get the solution?

Comment: The solution is $U[r,0]$ by definition.