# Are there any dynamic programming algorithms that combine solutions to sub-problems in a more 'dynamic' way?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

First of all, I now know that 'dynamic' has nothing to do with the dynamism of a dynamic programming algorithm. But I didn't before I studied them, and I was kind of disappointed that they all seem to rely on a pretty basic recursion. Are there any problems with more interesting optimal substructures?

Comment: I don't follow. It sounds like you just want examples of "interesting" DP problems? The whole point of a DP algorithm is to make the computation a basic recursion of a function of a small number of variables that each take as few values as possible.

Comment: For a problem that can be solved using DP, but for which the side constraints that enable optimal substructure are challenging to find, I suggest https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126885/facility-location-on-a-tree.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but your title vaguely reminds me of a common misconception that a DP algorithm can use the full information of a solution _instance_, rather than solution _value_. But please clarify what you mean by interesting optimal substructures.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, either. Can you provide an example of what you mean?